# Grafana react plugins with canvas inside

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I am trying to write a grafana **react** plugin with a canvas inside. I created my template with `npx @grafana/toolkit plugin:create my-plugin`. I ran this template with `yarn install`, `yarn dev --watch`. It works.

To test, I removed options in module.ts file like this

```
import { PanelPlugin } from '@grafana/data';
import { SimplePanel } from './SimplePanel';

export const plugin = new PanelPlugin(SimplePanel);
```

I modified SimplePanel.tsx file as follow

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { PanelProps } from '@grafana/data';

export class SimplePanel extends PureComponent<PanelProps> {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.refs.canvas)
        const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
        console.log(ctx)
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <canvas ref="canvas" width={300} height={300}/>
        );
    }
}
```

And I got the following error :

> Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'ReactInstance'.
>      Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'Component< any, {}, any>'.

How is it possible to add a canvas in grafana **react** plugin ?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Don't use string-refs, it's obsolete. Create a ref using React.createRef(), maybe it will help, becuase React appearently has problem with accessing the reference of canvas element.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @MateuszFalkowski. Thanks a lot. It works with React.createRef(). See answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MateuszFalkowski's comment, I manage to add a canvas :

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { PanelProps } from '@grafana/data';

export class SimplePanel extends PureComponent<PanelProps> {

    myCanvasRef = React.createRef<HTMLCanvasElement>()

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.myCanvasRef)
        const ctx = this.myCanvasRef.current!.getContext('2d');
        console.log(ctx)
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <canvas ref={this.myCanvasRef} width={300} height={300}/>
        );
    }
}
```